# How symfony read locale for php-translation

Tags: symfony, translation

I want to use [php-translation/symfony-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/php-translation/symfony-bundle) in my Symfony 4 project.

I have followed the [configuration step](https://php-translation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/symfony/index.html).

```
translation:
    locales: ["fr", "en", "de", "nl"]
    configs:
        applicationName:
            dirs: ['%kernel.project_dir%/templates', '%kernel.project_dir%/src']
            output_dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
            excluded_names: ['*TestCase.php', '*Test.php']
            excluded_dirs: [cache, data, logs]
            remote_storage: ['php_translation.adapter.loco']
```

But I got a problem. When I want to translate into language it doesn't work if I don't specify the locale.

```
 $trans = $translator->trans('portal.no_access', [], 'portal', $request->getLocale());
 $transWithoutLocale = $translator->trans('portal.no_access', [], 'portal');

var_dump($trans); ==> return 'string translated'
var_dump($transWithoutLocale); ==> return 'string in default locale format' ( fr )
var_dump($request->getLocale()); ==> return 'de'
```

How can I force the `translator` to use the Request locale like [symfony recommend it](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/translation/locale.html)

Comment: You are not using Symfony's Translator bundle. With Symfony's translator bundle you would be able not to specify the user's locale. But with this third party package, it would seem that you would need to. You either decorate the service and encapsulate the call, or just pass the request locale on each `trans()` call, which seems easy enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the translator doesn't read the request locale as said by @yivi, and I do not want to give the request locale to all my call to `trans`. I added a `Listener` that listen all `KernelEvents::REQUEST` and set `locale` into `Translator`:

```
class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /** @var TranslatorInterface */
    private $translator;

    /**
     * LocaleListener constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', 10],
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if (\method_exists($this->translator, 'setLocale')) {
            $this->translator->setLocale($request->getLocale());
        }
    }
}
```